# Nested Task - The current synchronizationcontext may not be used as a taskscheduler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, task-parallel-library

I've got a WPF MVVM application which has the concept of "services".

Each service method gets passed a callback as on of the parameters, it creates the `Task`, does the work and then calls the callback in the ViewModel in the continuation.

In one of my service methods the "work" involves synchronising databases and then loading the updated database from the DB. Another method counts the number of records in a table. Here are some simplified examples.

```
public void GetStudents(Action<IEnumerable<Student>> callback)
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
          Sync();
          return students;
    }).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
          callback(task.Result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
public void CountStudents(Action<int> callback)
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        return students.Count();
    }).ContinueWith(task => 
    {
        callback(task.Result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

These methods were called separately from different ViewModels and they worked as expected; however (isn't there always a however) I've added an event on synchronisation completed using the Prism `EventAggregator`. When sync has completed, if the Student table has been update I want to re-run the count method. The problem is because this is happening from the context of the other Task I'm getting this exception.

> "The current synchronizationcontext may not be used as a taskscheduler"

I've tried joining the Task to the parent task with `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` but that doesn't fix the issue.

The more I think about it I think I should move the `Task` creation to my ViewModels, it seems the most logical and correct place for it to be, but is there something I'm missing that means I don't have to do that in this instance?

Comment: BTW, with C# 5.0, your calling code would be much simpler (no more callbacks).

Comment: Yeah, I've only recently updated to .Net 4.5, I've not investigated the await stuff much yet. Are you suggesting that would be all that's needed to fix this?

Comment: I haven't seen that exception before, so I don't know what exactly is the issue. That means I have no idea if using `await` would fix this, I just suggested it as an alternative.

Comment: I think it's because they both synchronise back to the UI thread but the context of the first task doesn't have a scheduler to user to synchronise. I just tried passing the TaskScheduler as part of the arguments to the first Task but still get the same error. I might just have to bite the bullet and re-factor it to start the Tasks from the view model or use the async/await model.

Comment: If you haven't yet looked into `Asynchrony` and you're using .Net45, stop -> check out [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-011) -> continue. It's not deemed by quite a few folk as the best thing to happen to C# since LINQ for no reason :) and yes it could very likely help you simplify your current issue as well since you work in a much more synchronous mode of programming.

Comment: I've used it briefly but heard some vague criticism about state machines and wanted to investigate further before I committed to it. I guess the Task API effectively compiles to state machines too though.